# jQuery $('#myLink').text("UpdateValue") appending text, not overwriting?

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty replacing the text of a link with new text.

I have the following line

```
$('#myLink').text("UpdateValue");
```

This used to work before until I made a change to fix something that should have never been broken.. and now this is appending text & not replacing it.

Can somebody please confirm that it should replace the existing text, and not append the text to the existing text? Or am I going nuts??!!

Thanks

(Crazy) Dave

Comment: Please paste your code, because this code works very well - I've just checked it.

Comment: There's too much to paste.. I'll take your word on it because I've seen it working before (a million times!). I think there's another bug somewhere and it's manifesting itself by breaking my link text. This is the beginning of 'one of those days'

Comment: does the sample code in my answer that manifests this bug apply to your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a PEBKAC error.

a careless copy & paste resulted in the following being pasted into a UserControl:

```
<a id="lnkShowClipboard" class="ClipboardLink" href="#">
```

note the absence of `</a>`

For whatever reason the browser tried to complete the unfinished HTML in its own way & whatever way that was, jQuery didn't agree with it.

Thanks guys

Dave

Answer (score 2):

See this comment from http://api.jquery.com/text/:

-- QUOTE --

One quirk for anyone else experiencing
this:

```
<label id="myLabel" />
$("#myLabel").text("newText");
```

Will continue to append the string
newText instead of replacing it. You
need to specify the label as:

```
<label id="myLabel"></label>
```

Then it will correctly replace the text.

-- END QUOTE --

Does this apply to your code?

Comment: This is similar to the issue I was having but not the same. this is a complete <label /> where mine was an incomplete <a>